# Jenkinsfile build remotely - How to set 'Authentication token' from jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkinsfile project, which I want to trigger remotely (from script). I'm familiar with the 'Trigger builds remotely (e.g. from scripts)', but I think because I use Jenkinsfile (and not the Jenkins's GUI), I don't have option to save the token in the project settings.

So I'm trying to create 'Authentication Token' from Jenkinsfile, but I don't know how.
I tried the following code I found online, but I got `"Undefined section 'authenticationToken'"`:

```
pipeline {
  authenticationToken('mytokenn')
}
```

Do you know how to create token from jenkinsfile?

Comment: Why you setup the credential in Jenkins with Jenkins admin access, when you add the credential you can given an human readable id like `mysql-auth`, otherwise Jenkins assign a long string like `ba2e4f46-56f1-4467-ae97-17b3tyi43bt`.  You can pass the credential Id as String parameter when you trigger the Jenkinsfile job,  inside Jenkinsfile you can use `withCredentials()`,  Or add `credentials()` in `environments` for Declaretive Pipeline

Comment: @yong This has nothing to do with jenkins managed credentials, it was used to call remote jobs using the token specified in this directive